# Как взять данные из sqlite3 select в другой sqlite3 запрос в where?

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

**Основной вопрос и проблема**:

У меня есть две таблица - `roulette_users` и `users`. Мне нужно взять `user_id` из `roulette_users` и используя его сделать запрос `SELECT` из `users` где `user_id` в `1` и `2` столбце равны. Не понимаю как это сделать без внешнего `for`, может быть есть какие то вариации, где я могу приравнять `where` к `for` из первой таблицы?

Если просто прописать, `for user_game in users_game` - *Тут я беру данные из первой таблицы*, - то данные во второй таблиице не будут найдены и запрос будет пустым.

**Уточнение:**

Именно так мне нужно расписать, потому что потом выводится сообщение со всеми пользователями и их результатами. Если ставить это сообщение в `for`, то у меня выводится не одно сообщение, а множество сообщений - *их количество равно количеству пользователей в `roulette_users`*.

**Фрагмент из кода с выводом данных:**

```py
                cur.execute('SELECT user_id, bid, bid_money FROM roulette_users WHERE group_id=("%s")' % group_id)
                users_game = cur.fetchall()
                conn.commit()

                cur.execute('SELECT nickname, balance FROM users WHERE user_id=("%s")' % (for user_game[0] in users_game))
                users = cur.fetchall()
                conn.commit()
```

**Весь код:**

```py
    if message.chat.id < 0:
        if rt == 'го':
            conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
            cur = conn.cursor()

            cur.execute('SELECT group_id FROM roulette WHERE group_id=("%s")' % group_id)
            group_info = cur.fetchall()
            conn.commit()

            result = 2

            if len(group_info) == 0:
                return
            else:
                cur.execute('SELECT user_id, bid, bid_money FROM roulette_users WHERE group_id=("%s")' % group_id)
                users_game = cur.fetchall()
                conn.commit()

                cur.execute('SELECT nickname, balance FROM users WHERE user_id=("%s")' % (for user_game[0] in users_game))
                users = cur.fetchall()
                conn.commit()

                print(users)

                for user_game in users_game:
                    #  result = random.randint(0, 36)
                    bid = user_game[1]
                    bid_money = user_game[2]

                    if bid == result:
                        cur.execute('UPDATE users SET balance=balance+("%s") WHERE user_id=("%s")' % (
                            bid_money * 2, user_game[0]))
                        conn.commit()

                    cur.execute('DELETE FROM roulette_users WHERE group_id=("%s")' % group_id)
                    conn.commit()

                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Результаты рулетки: \n\n" + "\n".join(
                    f'[{user[0]}](tg://user?id={user_game[0]}) вы {f"выиграли {user_game[2] * 2}" if user_game[1] == result else f"проиграли {user_game[2]}"}'
                    for user_game in users_game for user in users), parse_mode='Markdown', disable_web_page_preview=True)

                cur.execute('DELETE FROM roulette WHERE group_id=("%s")' % group_id)
            cur.close()
            conn.close()
```

Возможно кто-то мог бы помочь с более правильным выводом итогового сообщения, чтобы я не сталкивался с проблемами, которые описал.

**Таблицы:**

*roulette:*
[image: roulette]

*roulette_users:*
[image: roulette_users]

*users:*
[image: users]

Comment: Делайте вложенный запрос или соединяйте при помощи JOIN. Добавьте в вопрос структуры таблиц, так тяжело сказать точно

Comment: можно уточнить как это сделать?

Comment: Минус за составление sql-запросов с помощью форматирования `%s`. Используйте привязку значений! https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-use-placeholders-to-bind-values-in-sql-queries

Comment: Не нужно вызывать `commit` после `select`.

Comment: @panickx запросы create, ну или название таблиц и какие столбцы в них

Comment: @CausonQ Добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Вашу задачу, то можно использовать оператор **JOIN**, который объединяет таблицы.
Затем добавить условие.

```
cur.execute("""SELECT users.*
    FROM roulette_users
    JOIN users ON roulette_users.user_id = users.user_id""")

data = cur.fetchall()


for i in data:
    print(i)
```

Есть также способ через **вложенный запрос**:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM roulette_users)""")

data = cur.fetchall()


for i in data:
    print(i)
```

**Дополнительно:**

Для запроса `SELECT` не нужно использовать `commit`.

Если задача отличается, то напишите в комментариях, я постараюсь изменить ответ на более подходящий.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM roulette_users tbl1
LEFT JOIN users tbl2 ON tbl2.user_id=tbl1.user_id
```

В выборке будут все столбцы из двух таблиц и соединены будут по полю user_id. Если я верно понял, что все такие нужно достать

`*` использовать нежелательно, лучше перечислить необходимые столбцы, например:

```
tbl1.user_id, tbl1.group_id, tbl2.balance
```

Comment: не очень понял как это использовать в моем случае

Comment: @panickx это sql запрос, который берет все записи из первой таблицы и добавляет к ней записи из users, где есть совпадение по user_id. Из вашего вопроса не понятно, что вы хотите получить по итогу. user_id в выборке должен быть один? Или их много? По каким данным должна быт фильтрация? "SELECT из users где user_id в 1 и 2 столбце равны." это как понять? Какие 1 и 2 столбцы? строки в этих столбцах имеют одинаковое значение?